# Find the name of a file except its directory

Tags: python, python-3.x

I used the following code to read all files in a folder:

```
files_path = [os.path.abspath(x) for x in os.listdir()]
fnames_transfer = [x for x in files_path if x.endswith(".mkv")]
```

Now I need to extract the name of the file except its directory. For example `fnames_transfer` is `E:\pythoncode\feature\1.mkv`. I need to extract `1.mkv` from this string. What should I do for this?

Comment: Why are you using `os.path.abspath()` in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

I used this `os.path.basename(fnames_transfer[i] )`and it works for me.